# Functions code running, but dont know how to call a certain function

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop, while-loop

This code is running, but not properly analyzing budget, prompting, or returning values correctly. I am having trouble writing the correct functions. When I run it, it prompts the user for their budget, and amount spent, then does nothing

```
month = 0
months = 0

def DescribeProgram():
 
   print("""\
This program uses a for loop to monitor your budget.
The program will prompt you to enter your budget, and amount spent
for a certain month and calculate if your were under or over budget.
You will have the option of choosing how many months you would like to
monitor.\n""")


def GetMonths():
    Months = input("Enter the number of months you want to analyze")
    return Months

def GetMonthBudgetandSpent(month):
      Mobudget = input("Enter the budget you have for the month")
      MoSpent = input("Enter the amount you spent this month")

def AnalyzeBudget(months):
    for month in range(1,months+1):
      print("\nMonth",month,":")
      print("=======")
MoBudget,MoSpent = GetMonthBudgetandSpent(month)

def main():
 DescribeProgram()
 months = GetMonths()
 AnalyzeBudget(months)

main()
```

Comment: Are you running the `main()` function?

Comment: @yees_7 yes i forgot to add that on this question, just updated it

Comment: I get a lot of errors when I run your code. `month` is not defined, `GetMonthBudgetandSpent()` doesn't return anything, etc. Are you getting any errors? You should be if you are running `main()` in your code.

Comment: Some tips:  1) use lowercase names for variables, 2) `input()` returns a string.  To use what it returns the way you are, you have to turn it into a number with `int()`.    3) The line `MoBudget,MoSpent = GetMonthBudgetandSpent(month)` is not in a good place...`month` will not be defined at that point in the code.  4) You probably want `return MoBudget,MoSpent` at the end of `GetMonthBudgetandSpent`.  Seems you have more work to do even once you've fixed these things.

Comment: Yes i got those errors, I added "month = 0" and "months = 0" at the start of the code, now i dont get errors, the code is just running weirdly

Comment: could anyone help revise my code?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def DescribeProgram():
 
   print("""\
This program uses a for loop to monitor your budget.
The program will prompt you to enter your budget, and amount spent
for a certain month and calculate if your were under or over budget.
You will have the option of choosing how many months you would like to
monitor.\n""")


def GetMonths():
    Months = int(input("Enter the number of months you want to analyze")) 
    return Months

def GetMonthBudgetandSpent(month):
      Mobudget = input("Enter the budget you have for the month")
      MoSpent = input("Enter the amount you spent this month")
      return Mobudget, MoSpent

def AnalyzeBudget(months):
    for month in range(1,months+1):
      print(f"\nMonth {month}:")
      print("=======")
      MoBudget,MoSpent = GetMonthBudgetandSpent(month)

def main():
 DescribeProgram()
 months = GetMonths()
 AnalyzeBudget(months)

main()
```

Only if `MoBudget` and `MoSpent` is at this level of indentation will the code work as of what I felt the code is for which is:

```
- Display what this program does
- Get no. of months to analyse budget
- For each month, take user input of budget and amount spend
```

You've not written any code to analyse the budget?

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am running your code and getting an error after the first prompt

Comment: Oh sorry, I've missed a line of code. You have to return the values of `Mobudget` and `MoSpent` after taking user input inside the function `GetMonthBudgetandSpent`

Comment: @Pillis , added those changes in the answer

Comment: Sorry! still getting errors after the first prompt such as: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: As somebody else already said, the input() function returns a string, so when the function AnalyzeBudget tries to do months+1 it throws an error because months is a str and 1 is an int. Just do int(input( ... )) instead of input( ... )